# Agrupar ciertas columnas y otras sumar con python o mysql

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

Tengo la siguiente tabla

[image: TABLA ORIGINAL]

He intentado un script que me sume los importes (columna importe) de los COD_FOR iguales, a la vez que me lo agrupe por fecha y en la columna transacciones me diga cuantos COD_FOR hay y no encuentro la manera de hacerlo.

Es decir, resultado final debe quedar en una fila con fecha, el COD_FOR que corresponda (4, 5 ó 6), el importe total del COD_FOR y cuantas transacciones hubo. Me da lo mismo que sea en mysql o mejor en python.

En el  ejemplo quedaría así:

[image: ESTARIA BUENO QUE QUEDE ASI:]

He intentado agrupar con pandas pero no encuentro la forma de agrupar: misma FECHA y mismo id_sede me sume los tres COD_FOR en IMPORTE. Me queda así pero no logro mi objetivo .

```py
cadena_conexion = 'mysql+pymysql://root@localhost:3306/parolacchia'
conexion = create_engine(cadena_conexion)
sql = 'SELECT * FROM inf_delivery'
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, con=conexion)
df = df[df['COD_FOR'].isin(['4', '5', '6'])]
df.groupby(['FECHA'])['IMPORTE'].sum()
print(df.head(30))
```

Comment: Necesitas!??, Aquí no se hacen trabajos, ayudamos con problemas en el código y tu no demuestras un interés por resolver el problema, así que no te ayudaremos.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque aquí no se hacen trabajos, se ayuda con problemas en el código

Comment: Este NO es un sitio donde hacemos programas gratis, es un sitio para ayudar con problemas con tu código. Que intentaste hacer para satisfacer esta necesidad?

Comment: De dónde sacas los datos de la tabla? Son resultado de una consulta SQL? Puedes usar pandas  (`pd.read_sql()`) para que convierta esa consulta en un dataframe, y después usar los métodos de pandas para computar la agrupación, suma, etc.

Comment: Leo un dbf con python y vuelco los datos a la tabla

Comment: Puedes usar [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41898905/1264820) para leer directamente tu tabla en un dataframe de pandas. Y después ya estudias un poco cómo usar pandas para lograr lo que buscas, o preguntas de nuevo.

Comment: que has intentado para resolver tu problema?

Comment: Eh intentado agrupar con pandas pero no encuentro la forma de agrupar: misma FECHA y mismo id_sede me sume los tres COD_FOR en IMPORTE.
Me queda asi pero no logro mi objetivo

cadena_conexion = 'mysql+pymysql://root@localhost:3306/parolacchia'
conexion = create_engine(cadena_conexion)
sql = 'SELECT * FROM inf_delivery'
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, con=conexion)
df = df[df['COD_FOR'].isin(['4', '5', '6'])]

df.groupby(['FECHA'])['IMPORTE'].sum()

print(df.head(30))

Comment: pues agrega eso a tu pregunta

Comment: Pero me figura cerrada. Podran reabrirla por favor?

Comment: obviamente, pero primero edita tu pregunta.

Comment: Listo, si hay algo que no corresponde por favor avisame, soy nuevo en esta plataforma y no quisiera hacer cosas como hice por lo que me cerraron la pregunta.

Comment: Agrega el código _como texto, con formato_. Las imágenes no se pueden depurar :)

Comment: Listo, pienso que ahi esta bien. Muchas gracias

Comment: Perdon, que me faltaría para que reabran la pregunta??

Comment: Eh Logrado hacer el script para que me agrupe tal como me pedian.
```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index = ['FECHA','id_sede' ], values = ['IMPORTE'], columns = ['COD_FOR'], aggfunc = ['sum', 'count'] )
```

Comment: Puedes responder a tu propia pregunta si deseas. Además así puedes ayudar a otros :D

Answer (score 1):

Por suerte eh logrado la agrupacion que me pedian, les paso el script que lo realice con pandas

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index = ['FECHA','id_sede' ], values = ['IMPORTE'], columns = ['COD_FOR'], aggfunc = ['sum', 'count'] )
```

Gracias!!